# Add text to bootstrap select input in same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add an asterisk to the select input field, I can easily do if I give the  my css but my condition is to use bootstrap 3.3.7 or lesser version and display the asterisk on the same line [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RPD.png).

```
<style>
.asterik-span{
    color: red; font-family: bold; font-size: 16px;
 }
.select-diag{
   width:90%;border:1px solid #ddd; border-radius:3px;height:32px;
 }
</style>
```

html

```
 <select  class="select-diag">
    <option >Value1</option>
    <option >Value2</option>
    <option >Value3</option>
</select>
<span class='pull-right asterik-span'>*</span>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahilAhmed/kxEML/365/)

Comment: question and fiddle are not same.

Comment: I'm sorry i had updated that.

Answer (score 0):

To use bootstrap only you can do this

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select  class="form-control">
    <option>Value1</option>
    <option>Value2</option>
    <option>Value3</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class='asterik-span'>*</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use font awesome. Is there any other way that I can do it without using anything else but just bootstrap.

Comment: Yes just change the font awesome icon `<i class="fa fa-asterisk" style="color:red" aria-hidden="true"></i>` to `<span class='asterik-span'>*</span>`

Comment: I believe thats what im doing you can see in the question. But i dont want to give custom styling. I want to use bootstrap. If i use bootstrap this is whats happening http://jsfiddle.net/rahilAhmed/k06t97wb/1/

Comment: Okay I believe I get how you want to achieve it now. Please see my updated answer for bootstrap only solution.

Comment: Fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/akassama/5oajkds5/](https://jsfiddle.net/akassama/5oajkds5/)

Comment: It's using input group, i had tried it aswell but it is entirely different than the screenshot image that I had mentioned in the question.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RPD.png)

Comment: Well... you would just have to use some css in that case.